# Multiple Parameters in GridView with multiple DataKeyNames passing same value for all parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

i have a gridview1 that I want to populate Gridview2

Gridview1 is declared like so:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gwDup" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="15" DataKeyNames="CASEID, Column2, ADATE, adddate"     AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` >
 <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Possible Duplicates" ReadOnly="True" 
        SortExpression="Column1" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CASEID" HeaderText="CASEID" 
        SortExpression="CASEID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2"            SortExpression="Column2" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ADATE" HeaderText="ADATE" SortExpression="ADATE" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AddDate" HeaderText="AddDate" 
        SortExpression="AddDate" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

i've put in a function to check the values being passed in when i click on select:

```
protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ControlParameter s in SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters)
        {
            Response.Write(s.ToString());
        }
    }
```

(i am using a debugger to get the value, not the response.write...)

though it seems the parameter name changes as it should, the value is always the same (of a caseID, which is the first parameter) am i doing something wrong here? how come the same value gets passed in for all 4 parameters?

Comment: If you are populating the first grid at the page load, maybe you forget `!IsPostback`.

Comment: it's populated with SqlDataSource, i don't do it in the back end...